# How can I share an internal disk via NFS? (What am I doing wrong?)

Tags: ubuntu, filesystems, nfs

I have an NFS server (machine A) that mounts a 4TB internal hard drive at `/data/Storage`, and exports `/data` to client (Machine B). If I put a regular file in `MachineA:/data`, you can see it in `MachineB:/space/MachineA`

But if you navigate to `MachineB:/space/MachineA/Storage` the folder appears empty. You can see its contents by navigating to `MachineA:/data/Storage`

## How can I access the disk from the client?

Here are the relevant configs

`MachineA:/etc/exports`:

```
/data           MachineB(rw,sync,no_subtree_check,no_root_squash)
```

`MachineA:/etc/fstab`:

```
UUID=385ab198-8b40-46f8-aacf-b6fe151d1962 /data/Storage ext4 errors=remount-ro 0 0
```

`MachineB:/etc/fstab`:

```
MachineA:/data     /space/MachineA    nfs     auto,_netdev,hard,bg,rsize=8192,wsize=8192,tcp,intr 0 0
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is normal behaviour. Mounted filesystems are normally not re-exported by nfs. You have to share both. E.g. you can add this to MachineA exports:

```
/data/Storage           MachineB(rw,sync,no_subtree_check,no_root_squash)
```

You might also need to add crossmnt option into the /data options in exports of MachineA or nohide to /data/Storage options in order to see it mounted as you expect. Do not forget to run exportfs to update exports.